# how do i search an excel document for a specific word and also build a new column with results from the search

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement

So i'm new to python and im trying to search an excel worksheet using python for the "ICD" in each row and create a new column with the results so, if a row contained the word "ICD" Then in the new column the word "yes" would appear if it didn't then the word "no" would appear.

so far i've tried a lot of different ways but im stuck because im new to this. Here is what i have so far. it took me a while to even find a way to import the excel document itself, now i have to find a way to add the new column and search each row and put the result. i know that i need a loop and i know that i need an if/else statement but i dont know where to put them or wha to put in them. im using python 3.7

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\New folder\CrohnsD.xlsx')
print (df)
import xlsxwriter
ICD=[
    str = df
    str.find("ICD",[ 0,[ 1057]])\
    if row contains "ICD"


]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has native excel reading support, so you don't need xlrd or xlsxwriter unless you have complex output formatting requirements.  If you're just reading, adding a column, and writing you can use pandas for all of that.

You can use a lambda function to check all the rows at once.  This may seem a little advanced, but `.apply(lambda)` on `axis=1` will perform whatever logic you assign to each row of your dataframe.  we can then use `.str .contains() and .any()` to check each for for the presents of `'a'`

```
data = [['a','b','c'],['a','d','e'],['x','y','z']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a new column that contains True or False depending on if any of the values in that row contain the string 'a'
df['has_letter_a'] = df.apply(lambda row: True if row.str.contains('a').any() else False, axis=1)
```

Output

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  has_letter_a
0  a  b  c          True
1  a  d  e          True
2  x  y  z         False
```

Comment: thank you. i am getting a better understanding but since already have df = to my excel file how would i get it to search each row of the excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the basic pandas string functions -- no need for anything fancy. Looking for whether a column of text contains a particular text string? Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['abc','defgICD','hijicd','klm']})
df['icd'] = df['x'].str.contains('icd', case=False)
```

returns:

```
         x    icd
0      abc  False
1  defgICD   True
2   hijicd   True
3      klm  False
```

See the help page for `str.contains` for some documentation on the options you can use. In particular, you can specify whether you match based on case (in which case the pattern you match needs to be exact) or whether you match `icd`, `ICD`, `iCd`, etc.

*Opinion*: As you gain more experience with programming, and even Excel, I'd recommend sticking to boolean True/False values rather than coding 'Yes'/'No', as it's just more straightforward, easier to remember, etc. If you need to present something to a manager/client/etc., you can replace True/False with something else as a last step.

Comment: thank you. i am getting a better understanding but since already have df = to my excel file how would i get it to search each row of the excel file

Comment: @mixjr365cool You read in the Excel file as you already have done, using `df = pd.read_excel(r'...')`. Then you apply whatever commands you want to execute, and then export to a new Excel file using [`df.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).